# Upgrading kube-prometheus-stack helm from 51.10.0 to 53.0.0 problem

Tags: performance

Secret "prometheus-prometheus" in namespace "monitoring" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "kube-prometheus-stack"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "monitoring"

i dont know what i should do.